# windows 8 item index inside groupeditemspage

Tags: c#, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I'm trying to create different tile sizes for the first item in each group of the GroupedItemsPage template with the data template selector.  Is there a way to get the group index and the item index within the group for each item?   If not, is the only way to use custom properties of the item?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer is no. Add an index property to your model.

http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2012/08/windows-8-beauty-tip-using.html